# Ошибка при переносе JEE проекта на сервер

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла проблема при использовании связки Java+Hibernate+JSP+Tomcat. Когда проект и база данных MySQL располагаются на локальном компьютере, все работает идеально. Однако, после переноса на сервер возникает следующая ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.develop.test.utils.HibernateUtils

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.develop.test.utils.HibernateUtils
```

Читал, что это может быть связано с секцией **static** конфигурационного файла HibernateUtils.java:

```
public class HibernateUtils {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public HibernateUtils() { }

static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }    
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Конфиг:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://<мой хост>.ru:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Mapping files -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Как можно побороть проблему?

Спасибо!

Comment: все зависит от того как вы собираете прожект, еси без мавена то советую прикрутить его (или грейдл). если с ним значит неправильно сконфигурирован импорт.

Comment: Проект собирается в NetBeans с помощью Maven, затем отправляется на удаленный сервер с установленным Tomcat. Maven на сервере отсутствует, может ли это вызывать проблему?

Что значит "неправильно сконфигурирован импорт"? Где это смотреть? Библиотеки лежать в .war файле.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть вызвана отсутствием импортируемых классов. Убедитесь в том, что состав библиотек локально и на сервере идентичен - как в вашем приложении, так и в папке библиотек `Tomcat`. Это может решить как конкретно эту проблему, так и вероятность возникновения таких же ошибок в других классах, и является более универсальным и надёжным решением.

Альтернативно, чтобы точечно решить именно проблему этого класса, проверьте все импорты (`import`) в классе `ru.develop.test.utils.HibernateUtils`, и обеспечьте наличие на сервере библиотек с импортируемыми классами. Есть одно НО - у импортируемых библиотек могут быть свои импорты, и отследить их все вручную может быть затруднительным. Поэтому лучше всё же сверить сразу весь состав библиотек, для этого обычно требуется сравнить только две пары папок: папка библиотек вашего приложения и папка библиотек `Tomcat`.

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ответ! Библиотеки находятся в .war файле. Сейчас на всякий случай скопировал их в папку %tomcat_home%/lib

Comment: Копировать в %tomcat_home%/lib из war не стоит, просто сверить %tomcat_home%/lib у вас и на сервере, и сверить WEB-INF/lib также. Как вариант - проверить версию Java.